# how to define a callback can insert function in other place? Javascript es5

Tags: javascript, callback

A.file

```
function Carousel(){

  ~~~~~~ code ~~~~~~

  this.add = function(data){   
    do_something()
    self.addCallback.call(this, arguments)
  };

  this.remove = function(data){
    do_something()
    this.removeCallback.call(this, arguments)
  };

  ~~~~~~ code ~~~~~~    
}

Carousel.prototype.addCallback = function(){};
Carousel.prototype.removeCallback = function(){};
```

B.file

```
carousel = new Carousel();

carousel.addCallback = (function(data){

// I want the data from A.file, but i can't ! heeeeeelp~

  do_something(data)
  carousel.addCallback()
  do_something(data)
})();
```

The problem is i can't get the `data` from A.file in B.file.

In my case, i need to inset some callback after create or remove actions.

Does this way correct? Could someone can share more trick, magic or correct above! Really really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

A.file

```
function Carousel(){

  this.add = function(data){   
    do_something()
    self.addCallback.call(this, data)
  };
}

Carousel.prototype.addCallback = function(){};
```

B.file

```
carousel = new Carousel();

carousel.addCallback = function(data){

  do_bbb_things(data)
};
```

Then execute carousel.add('abc'), will call the do_bbb_things('abc') after.